# Is there a built-in function to keep command window open in PyInstaller

Tags: python, command-line, pyinstaller

I'm creating an executable from my Python script now, and when something fails in the script (for example, a file is not present), I quit the script with `sys.exit('*Enter reason here*')`. This works excellent in the terminal view, because the output is still visible in the window. However, when I build an executable, the window is closed immediately, and the reason why the scripts ends, is not readable.

Is there an option to keep the command window open (preferably in PyInstaller)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an option:

Because `sys.exit()`raises the error `SystemExit` it can be catch in a try-except statement. Even the text within `sys.exit()` can be catched! Because there is only one function that is called (main_function), it is a short and comprehensible option:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main_function()
    except SystemExit as e:
        print 'Error!', e
        print 'Press enter to exit (and fix the problem)'
        raw_input()
```

Comment: Is this good programming? Shouldn't you raise an exception in your code and then catch the exception and then exit? Btw. this has nothing to do with pyinstaller.

Comment: The `sys.exit()` in the `main_function()` is in the except block. So the exceptions are taken care of, and the error message is shown in this way. I know that this has nothing to do with PyInstaller, but I didn't see anything in the --help of PyInstaller that was going in this direction